# Ubuntu 11.10 Crashing (maybe "gnome-session: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server")

Tags: 11.10, unity, lightdm

MY Ubuntu 11.10 crashed the 2nd time in few hours recently, I looked at the syslog and pasted it below. I think the cause might be the either of the following lines?

- `gnome-session: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server`
- `apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/bin/evince" name="/run/udev/data/b8:4" pid=9150 comm="evince" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0`

---

```
Jan 24 14:39:01 JM CRON[9151]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jan 24 14:39:03 JM kernel: [ 4375.718487] type=1400 audit(1327387143.521:53): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/bin/evince" name="/run/udev/data/b8:4" pid=9158 comm="evince" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Jan 24 14:39:03 JM kernel: [ 4376.102319] type=1400 audit(1327387143.905:54): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/bin/evince" name="/run/udev/data/b8:4" pid=9158 comm="evince" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Jan 24 14:39:05 JM kernel: [ 4377.980823] type=1400 audit(1327387145.785:55): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/bin/evince" name="/run/udev/data/b8:4" pid=9158 comm="evince" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Jan 24 14:40:50 JM kernel: [ 4483.073773] type=1400 audit(1327387250.945:56): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/bin/evince" name="/run/udev/data/b8:4" pid=9168 comm="evince" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Jan 24 14:41:50 JM kernel: [ 4542.828368] type=1400 audit(1327387310.741:57): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/bin/evince" name="/run/udev/data/b8:4" pid=9170 comm="evince" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Jan 24 14:45:53 JM kernel: [ 4785.805094] type=1400 audit(1327387553.873:58): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/bin/evince" name="/run/udev/data/b8:4" pid=9332 comm="evince" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Jan 24 14:45:53 JM kernel: [ 4785.842048] type=1400 audit(1327387553.909:59): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/bin/evince" name="/run/udev/data/b8:4" pid=9335 comm="evince" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Jan 24 14:45:53 JM kernel: [ 4785.881980] type=1400 audit(1327387553.949:60): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/bin/evince" name="/run/udev/data/b8:4" pid=9335 comm="evince" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Jan 24 14:45:53 JM kernel: [ 4785.889949] type=1400 audit(1327387553.957:61): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/bin/evince" name="/run/udev/data/b8:4" pid=9335 comm="evince" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Jan 24 14:45:53 JM kernel: [ 4785.918806] type=1400 audit(1327387553.985:62): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/bin/evince" name="/run/udev/data/b8:4" pid=9338 comm="evince" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Jan 24 14:45:53 JM kernel: [ 4785.918896] type=1400 audit(1327387553.985:63): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/bin/evince" name="/run/udev/data/b8:4" pid=9335 comm="evince" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Jan 24 14:45:53 JM kernel: [ 4785.919014] type=1400 audit(1327387553.985:64): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/bin/evince" name="/run/udev/data/b8:4" pid=9340 comm="evince" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Jan 24 14:45:53 JM kernel: [ 4785.920491] type=1400 audit(1327387553.989:65): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/bin/evince" name="/run/udev/data/b8:4" pid=9339 comm="evince" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Jan 24 14:45:53 JM kernel: [ 4785.925745] type=1400 audit(1327387553.993:66): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/bin/evince" name="/run/udev/data/b8:4" pid=9335 comm="evince" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Jan 24 14:45:58 JM kernel: [ 4790.399063] type=1400 audit(1327387558.469:67): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/bin/evince" name="/run/udev/data/b8:4" pid=9338 comm="evince" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Jan 24 14:46:00 JM kernel: [ 4791.931711] audit_printk_skb: 24 callbacks suppressed
Jan 24 14:46:00 JM kernel: [ 4791.931716] type=1400 audit(1327387560.001:76): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/bin/evince" name="/run/udev/data/b8:4" pid=9338 comm="evince" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Jan 24 14:46:00 JM kernel: [ 4791.931928] type=1400 audit(1327387560.001:77): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/bin/evince" name="/run/udev/data/b8:4" pid=9351 comm="evince" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Jan 24 14:46:00 JM kernel: [ 4792.299099] type=1400 audit(1327387560.369:78): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/bin/evince" name="/run/udev/data/b8:4" pid=9338 comm="evince" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Jan 24 14:46:00 JM kernel: [ 4792.531328] type=1400 audit(1327387560.601:79): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/bin/evince" name="/run/udev/data/b8:4" pid=9338 comm="evince" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Jan 24 14:46:10 JM kernel: [ 4802.221498] type=1400 audit(1327387570.297:80): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/bin/evince" name="/run/udev/data/b8:4" pid=9351 comm="evince" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Jan 24 14:46:16 JM kernel: [ 4808.232986] type=1400 audit(1327387576.313:81): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/bin/evince" name="/run/udev/data/b8:4" pid=9351 comm="evince" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Jan 24 14:46:22 JM kernel: [ 4814.277205] type=1400 audit(1327387582.361:82): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/bin/evince" name="/run/udev/data/b8:4" pid=9351 comm="evince" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Jan 24 14:46:25 JM kernel: [ 4817.523485] type=1400 audit(1327387585.609:83): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/bin/evince" name="/run/udev/data/b8:4" pid=9351 comm="evince" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Jan 24 14:46:29 JM kernel: [ 4821.784386] type=1400 audit(1327387589.873:84): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/bin/evince" name="/run/udev/data/b8:4" pid=9351 comm="evince" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Jan 24 14:53:52 JM gnome-session[1326]: Gdk-WARNING: gnome-session: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.#012
Jan 24 06:54:01 JM rtkit-daemon[1479]: Successfully made thread 9629 of process 9629 (n/a) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
Jan 24 06:54:01 JM rtkit-daemon[1479]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Jan 24 14:54:01 JM pulseaudio[9629]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Stale PID file, overwriting.
Jan 24 06:54:01 JM rtkit-daemon[1479]: Successfully made thread 9631 of process 9629 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Jan 24 06:54:01 JM rtkit-daemon[1479]: Supervising 2 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Jan 24 06:54:01 JM rtkit-daemon[1479]: Successfully made thread 9664 of process 9629 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Jan 24 06:54:01 JM rtkit-daemon[1479]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Jan 24 06:54:01 JM rtkit-daemon[1479]: Successfully made thread 9665 of process 9629 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Jan 24 06:54:01 JM rtkit-daemon[1479]: Supervising 4 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
```

Comment: It's not just you, I'm also affected. It covers more than just your authenticated user, the guest account won't work either. Graphically it looks like login succeeds, the mouse appears and then you're dumped back to the login screen.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: I am having the same issue....:( I will file a bug if there is none so far. Don't know if I should fall back to an older driver or try to find a solution for this.